# Third Monitor without video card support?

Tags: windows-xp, video, multiple-monitors

I am getting a new monitor and I am wondering if there is a way to keep my old one and go to 3 monitors.  (I have 2 now.)

My laptop/docking station only supports 2 monitors, so any solution would have to have to not rely on the video card having 3 ports.

Software, external hardware?  I do have access to an extra machine I am not using if that helps.  (Maybe there is some way to make the extra machine be a slave video driver?)

Any ideas?

My laptop specs are:
Dell, XP, Core 2 Duo 2 Ghz, 4GB Ram, 250 GB HD (SSD), Nvidia Quadro FX 4800m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**USB to DVI External Video Card, High Resolution, 1600 x 1200**](http://sewelldirect.com/USB-to-DVI-External-Video-Card-High-Resolution.asp)

[image]

That should do and the price is reasonable.

If you have a spare computer, you may use **[ZoneScreen](http://www.zoneos.com/index.htm)** to clone or extend the display of your laptop to another computer. over a network connection.

*ZoneScreen is freeware.*

Comment: Molly, have you had good luck with ZoneScreen? I haven't tried for a couple years, but last I did it was disappointing for performance.

Comment: works fine for me, doesn't conflict with Synergy which i'm also using. however, don't expect miracles from such a solution in terms of speed, they're by no means a substitute for a real graphics card. for serious work i'd choose the external graphics adapter.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the extra PC, look into [MaxiVista](http://www.maxivista.com/).

> MaxiVista turns any spare Desktop,
>   Laptop or Netbook PC into a dual
>   monitor for your primary computer. No
>   extra multi monitor hardware is
>   required. Simply extend program
>   windows across multiple screens as if
>   it were one big monitor. Increase your
>   productivity by using multiple
>   monitors.
>
> Now with Windows 32/64 Bit Vista and
>   Windows 7 support.